# How to know if libspotify can be used on my device

Tags: linux, spotify

I own a VU+ Duo, which is a SAT Receiver similar to a Dreambox. I also have a Spotify Premium subscription and would be interested in developing a Spotify plugin for my device.

I can get to libspotify library compiled for different processor architectures from the Spotify developer page. However, I can't find enough info to see be sure if any of these libraries will work on my device. I just know that it has a Broadcom BCM7335 chipset.

So basically my question is: how do I find out if any of the provided spotify libraries works on the VU+. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have never developed on a Linux based platform before. Only windows. So my knowledge is rather limited. But I'm willing to learn it. But first I would like to know if it is even worth the effort.

Can anyone provide me with some details. 
Basically, what I would like to know is this: Is there a Linux command which could just tell me: Yes or no, this device can use a given library? Or maybe I will need to write a basic program which uses the library and see of it compiles?

Comment: Unless things have changed, you will need a Spotify key to compile into your binary if you're going to use the official library. You might want to look into libopenspotify or libdespotify to get something to work with and do some simple tests.

Comment: @TonyTonk You still need a Spotify key to use libSpotify, and they're freely available to all Premium subsribers. What's that got to do with the question?

Comment: @HonkyTonk: You wouldn't happen to know if those libraries are still compliant with the official libspotify API as it looks like there hasn't been any updates for some time now. I can't find any info on this.

Comment: @iKenndac I suggested other libraries as alternatives since I don't know if Spotify supplies any MIPS builds. libdespotify, for example, does not require anything more than the code to run and be used together with a premium account and stream the data.

Comment: As far as I know, libopenspotify has as one of its main goals to be fully compliant with the official libspotify. libdespotify is a reverse engineering effort that is very much as is when it comes to functionality. But it does work for keeping playlists, playing music and searching which, to me, is the core functionality needed for any player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the BCM7335 chipset uses MIPS, and there isn't a MIPS build of libSpotify available on the Spotify developer website, so it doubt you'd be able to get very far.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of :-( So sad. Maybe I'll try to contact Spotify and ask if they'll be willing to compile the library for a MIPS based processor. Or I'll have a look a libdespotify or libopenspotify like HonkyTonk suggested.

Comment: Yes, please do contact us — there's an email address on the Hardware tab of http://developer.spotify.com/.

Comment: I have sent an email to the address provided on the Hardware tab of the developer site. Hope that's OK.